# how to multiply by batches in keras backend or tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have two tensors of shape (batch size,15,500) , (batch size,500,98)
I want to Multiply them as matrix Multiplication for each batch size to obtain (batch size,15,98)
How can I do that in tensorflow or keras backend
can I use Batch dot

Comment: Are they layers or `tensor`s inside custom function?

Comment: tensors inside custom function

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
A = K.placeholder((None, 15, 500))
B = K.placeholder((None, 500, 98))

C = tf.einsum("ijk,ljn->ijn", A, B)

In [84]: C
Out[84]: <tf.Tensor 'einsum/transpose_2:0' shape=(?, 15, 98) dtype=float32>
```

This says contract on index j, which is what a single matrix multiplication would look like, and repeat that for index i